# How do I get a list of all available shell commands

Tags: bash, shell

In a typical Linux shell (bash) it is possible to to hit tab twice, to get a list of all available shell commands.

Is there a command which has the same behaviour? I want to pipe it into `grep` and search it.

Comment: The answers below tell you how. I think you'd benefit more if you tell us why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command to list all available commands and aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948008/linux-command-to-list-all-available-commands-and-aliases)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use compgen. For example:

```
compgen -c
```

You also could grep it, like this:

```
compgen -c | grep top$
```

Source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/compgen-linux-command/

Answer (score 3):

You can list the directories straight from `$PATH` if you tweak the field separator first. The parens limit the effect to the one command, so use: `(...) | grep ...`

```
(IFS=': '; ls -1 $PATH)
```

Answer (score 1):

"tab" twice & "y" prints all files in the paths of $PATH. So just printing all files in PATH is sufficient.

Just type this in the shell:

```
 # printf "%s\n" ${PATH//:/\/* } > my_commands
```

This redirect all the commands to a file "my_commands".

Answer (score 1):

List all the files in your `PATH variable` (ls all the directories in the PATH). The default user and system commands will be in /bin and /sbin respectively but on installing some software we will add them to some directory and link it using PATH variable.

Answer (score 0):

There may be things on your path which aren't actually executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
for d in ${PATH//:/ }; do
  for f in "$d"/*; do
    test -x "$f" && echo -n "$f "
  done
done
echo ""
```

This will also print paths, of course.  If you only want unqualified filenames, it should be easy to adapt this.

Funny, StackOverflow doesn't know how to handle syntax highlighting for this.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>y</kbd>

Comment: For my setup, I just need to hit tab once

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @ghoti, but using find:

```
#!/bin/sh
for d in ${PATH//:/ }; do
    find $d -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash uses a builtin command named 'complete' to implement the tab feature.

I don't have the details to hand, but the should tell you all you need to know:

```
help complete
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(IFS=':'; find $PATH -maxdepth 1 -type f -executable -exec basename {} \; | sort | uniq)
```

It doesn't include shell builtins though.

Answer (score 0):

*An answer got deleted, I liked it most, so I'm trying to repost it:*

**compgen is of course better**

```
echo $PATH | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -n 1 ls -1
```

I found this to be the most typical shell thing, I think it works also with other shells (which I doubt with things like `IFS=':'` )

Clearly, there maybe problems, if the file is not an executable, but I think for my question, that is enough - I just want to `grep` my output - which means searching for some commands.