# How to get a list of available `heroku run` commands?

Tags: heroku

There are several native Linux commands not available using `heroku run`, for example `heroku run less filename` and `heroku run apropos`. **How do I get a list of all available `heroku run` commands?**

Btw I'm just trying to look into some dirs and files from my application but for some reason I can't view them with the available commands. I tried `cd my_project/my_application && ls` but it just shows the `ls` of `my_project` for some reason.

Comment: Not tested, but you can execute any linux command as `heroku run bash -c "your command"`. Also, you can open a linux shell and execute commands.

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, `heroku run bash -c "apropos"` outputs:
`Running 'bash' attached to terminal... failed`
`!    Resource not found`

Comment: Open a bash and look for command path with where is.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly, but if you meant "do `which bash`", this returned `/bin/bash`.

Comment: sorry, I explain: execute `heroku run bash`, then, into bash, execute `whereis less` , finally execute `heroku run bash -c "/usr/bin/less /your/file"` (where /usr/bin is the full path for this command).

Comment: Doing `heroku run bash` puts me into a prompt, from there I executed `whereis less`. It just returned a blank path like this `less:`. But anyway, you actually answered two questions I had. I now can easliy navigate in the folders with the `bash` command! Also just doing `ls` in the `/bin` dir gives me a list of the commands I wanted! Please can you make a seperate answer with this info so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get command list doing a `ls` in `/bin` *Heroku* folder. Follow this steps:

- Login into *Heroku* via bash: `heroku run bash`
- List bin commands: `ls /bin`

Remember than you are in a cloned instance. All changes you do in filesystem will be dropped exiting shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can bash into a dyno using `heroku run bash` and run this command:

```
echo -n $PATH | xargs -d : -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -executable -type f -printf '%P\n' | sort -u
```

(source: [Linux command to list all available commands and aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948008/linux-command-to-list-all-available-commands-and-aliases))