# Command to list all available commands in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, compgen

I’d like to programmatically get a list of all the available commands in Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`). Is there something like [`compgen -c` in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/949006/96656), but for Windows?

Comment: Funny... I ran `compgen -c` in WSL to see what it looked like and the output included Windows programs (together with DLLs) xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This provides CMD specific commands.

```
help
```

and to page the output use this

```
help | more
```

Comment: Thanks. That doesn’t seem to list all available commands, though. Is there a way to include things like `con2prt`, `msinfo32`, `regsvr32`, `rundll32` etc.?

Comment: `dir c:\windows\system32\*.exe` - but I'm quite sure, that's much more than you want (for example, there is also `calc.exe`). On the other hand - it IS a list of all available (external) commands - well, to be complete, you have to do it on all folders in your `%path%`